# Workflow formula field update

Tags: community, formula, workflow

I want to update the field through workflow that price__c = 1000 and price__c is a number data type.
But i am unable to field update, it is throwing an error:

> Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Number)

[image]

Comment: You're trying to set result of comparison between your field and number to result field, just leave it as ```1000```, that should work.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova seems like an answer to me. Post it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Copying my comment to an answer as it seems it helped.

You are trying to set the result of comparison between your field and number to the result field, the result is Boolean and it does not suit your formula. Just leave it as `1000`, that should work.